# Text file to excel file for large amount of data

Tags: perl

I want to write a script which will take data from a flat file and write it to an excel. My code is below

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel;
my $workbook  = Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->new( 'deep.xls' );
my $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet();

$worksheet->write( 0, 0, "DEEP" ) ;
$worksheet->write( 0, 1, "RIJU" );
$worksheet->write( 1, 0, "Sukhi" );
$worksheet->write( 1, 1, "Abhilash" );

$workbook->close;
```

And my flat file contains below

```
FILE_NAME                   Start_Timestamp     End_Timestamp   Record Count    Inbound/Outbound
OmahaTran.txt               1/25/2018 3:40      1/25/2018 3:40  90390           Inbound
concord                     1/24/2018 20:50     1/24/2018 20:50 8631            Inbound
iDine:RewardsNetwork 5220   1/24/2018 12:01     1/24/2018 12:04 218985          Outbound
nashville                   1/25/2018 4:30      1/25/2018 4:32  6810            Inbound
nstrans0.20180125           1/25/2018 2:00      1/25/2018 2:00  124573          Inbound
```

Since i am new to perl can anyone help me out how to retrieve "FILE_NAME" "End_Timestamp" and "Record Count" column from the text file and write it to an excel

Comment: https://code-maven.com/slides/perl-programming/fixed-width-record

Comment: You have a great answer, but how does "large amount of data" matter?

Comment: If the file is huge, instead of putting it all into memory before writing it out, i.e. the way `Spreadsheet::WriteExcel` does, you could instead just print out of csv file line by line, which Excel should be able to import.  That way, it doesn't matter how large the file is.

Comment: @xxfelixxx Ah, thank you. I didn't know that the module takes the whole file.

Comment: @zdim Actually that was a guess based on the usage pattern...reading the docs indicates that it might not be totally true..it looks like it tries to write tempoary files along the way to speed things up.

Answer (score 1):

You can parse your input as a fixed-width file.  You already know how to write the excel once you have the fields...

**parse_fixed.pl**

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my $usage = "usage: $0 file\n";
my $file = $ARGV[0] or die $usage;
-f $file or die $usage;

# Create $workbook and $worksheet objects here.

open my $fh, "<$file" or die "Unable to open '$file' : $!";
while(my $line = <$fh>) {
    chomp($line);
    # Unpack the fields, first field 27 chars, then 19 chars, etc.
    # perldoc -f pack
    my @fields = unpack("A27 A19 A17 A16 A20", $line);

    # Remove leading and trailing whitespace for each field
    # perldoc -f map
    # perldoc perlretut
    my ($file_name, $start, $stop, $record_count, $direction)
        = map { s|^\s*||; s|\s*||; $_ } @fields; 

    print("filename: '$file_name', start: '$start', stop: '$stop', record_count: '$record_count', direction: '$direction'\n");

    # Add $worksheet->write(...) lines for each field here.

}

# Close $workbook here.
```

**output**

```
perl parse_fixed.pl input

filename: 'FILE_NAME', start: 'Start_Timestamp', stop: 'End_Timestamp', record_count: 'Record Count', direction: 'Inbound/Outbound'
filename: 'OmahaTran.txt', start: '1/25/2018 3:40', stop: '1/25/2018 3:40', record_count: '90390', direction: 'Inbound'
filename: 'concord', start: '1/24/2018 20:50', stop: '1/24/2018 20:50', record_count: '8631', direction: 'Inbound'
filename: 'iDine:RewardsNetwork 5220', start: '1/24/2018 12:01', stop: '1/24/2018 12:04', record_count: '218985', direction: 'Outbound'
filename: 'nashville', start: '1/25/2018 4:30', stop: '1/25/2018 4:32', record_count: '6810', direction: 'Inbound'
filename: 'nstrans0.20180125', start: '1/25/2018 2:00', stop: '1/25/2018 2:00', record_count: '124573', direction: 'Inbound'
```

[Maven.com dealing with fixed-width records](https://code-maven.com/slides/perl-programming/fixed-width-record)

[perldoc -f pack](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html)

Comment: I have added below after your script    ------>    my $workbook  = Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->new( 'deep.xls' );
        my $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet();
        $worksheet->write( 0, 0, $file_name ) ;
        $worksheet->write( 0, 1, $stop );
        $worksheet->write( 0, 2, $record_count );

        $workbook->close;

Comment: ANd i am getting below output in excel nstrans0.20180125 1/25/2018 2:00 124573
But i want all the records from the 3 columns. Could you please help me out

Comment: What is the issue?  You iterate over each line, call  `$worksheet->write(..)` inside the loop.  Put `$worksheet->close` outside of the loop.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am now able to fetch all the data

Answer (score 1):

This is a pattern that I use a lot for converting fixed-width fields to comma-separated values. Of course, Excel will happily import this CSV data, doing most of the work for for you

It assumes that the fields extend from the start of one header string to the start of the next, and uses built-in array `@-` to determine where each one starts. Header strings may contain single spaces; more than one consecutive space terminates the string

I hope it's clear that the value of `$template` is printed only for diagnostics, and isn't part of the CSV data

It's a simple matter to remove the `print` statement that outputs the comma-separated header strings if they're not wanted. Alternatively, it's also trivial to remove the row from the spreadsheet after import if desired

The `DATA` file handle is used for convenience and demonstration purposes. Ordinarily you will probably want to `open` a specific file and use that file handle, or just use `<>` to read from files specified as command line parameters

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

my $head;

my $template = do {

    $head = <DATA>;

    my @template;
    my $prev;

    while ( $head =~ / \S+ (?: [ ] \S+ )* /xg ) {
        push @template, defined $prev ? 'A' . ( $-[0] - $prev ) : '@' . $-[0];
        $prev = $-[0];
    }

    push @template, 'A*';

    "@template";
};

say qq{Pack format "$template"\n};

say join ',', unpack $template, $head;

while ( <DATA> ) {
    say join ',', unpack $template, $_;
}


__DATA__
FILE_NAME                   Start_Timestamp     End_Timestamp   Record Count    Inbound/Outbound
OmahaTran.txt               1/25/2018 3:40      1/25/2018 3:40  90390           Inbound
concord                     1/24/2018 20:50     1/24/2018 20:50 8631            Inbound
iDine:RewardsNetwork 5220   1/24/2018 12:01     1/24/2018 12:04 218985          Outbound
nashville                   1/25/2018 4:30      1/25/2018 4:32  6810            Inbound
nstrans0.20180125           1/25/2018 2:00      1/25/2018 2:00  124573          Inbound
```

#### output

```
Pack format "@0 A28 A20 A16 A16 A*"

FILE_NAME,Start_Timestamp,End_Timestamp,Record Count,Inbound/Outbound
OmahaTran.txt,1/25/2018 3:40,1/25/2018 3:40,90390,Inbound
concord,1/24/2018 20:50,1/24/2018 20:50,8631,Inbound
iDine:RewardsNetwork 5220,1/24/2018 12:01,1/24/2018 12:04,218985,Outbound
nashville,1/25/2018 4:30,1/25/2018 4:32,6810,Inbound
nstrans0.20180125,1/25/2018 2:00,1/25/2018 2:00,124573,Inbound
```